# RSA private key detected; please remove and revoke it if this is a leak

Tags: node.js, gitlab-ci, node-modules

Good morning,

I just added the *Security/Secret-Detection.gitlab-ci.yml* in my project and this "leak" appeared in one of my node modules:

> RSA private key detected; please remove and revoke it if this is a leak.
> frontend/node_modules/node-ipc/local-node-ipc-certs/private/server.key:1

[error message in GIT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4FRl.png)

This mentioned file is not being pushed into the repository, does it still represents a leak?

Thanks!

Comment: I do not think this is **git** related.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message points to the file that it thinks may be a leak. It's inside `node_modules`, which contain third-party packages installed by NPM or any other common JS package manager. Even though you don't check `node_modules` into your repository, you will likely have a step that calls `npm install` which will install this package.

You can find the file referenced in the error message at the `node-ipc` repo here:

[local-node-ipc-certs/private/server.key](https://github.com/RIAEvangelist/node-ipc/blob/088a1ca4d5fe5d175c43ee41718b72b017f6f6a4/local-node-ipc-certs/private/server.key)

Reading through the package, that file is only referenced from the `/examples` directory, to demonstrate how you would configure a certificate. It doesn't contain any real private data, but it is a valid RSA private key so Gitlab is warning you that you should be aware of it.

**tl;dr** - it's safe to ignore this particular warning.

Comment: Thanks for the analysis, it's now clearer. I just dismissed all the errors related to this leak, after running the pipeline again, it didn't appeared anymore.